# Activity launched from service starts from scratch

Tags: android, service

I am building an app to test all the hardware buttons on device. For Home button, I am starting a service and relaunching the same activity from that service(updating the UI that home button test is performed). The problem is, all the previous progress of tests is erased and this activity starts from scratch when it is relaunched. For ex: I performed back key, menu, volume up key and home in the given order. When activity is relaunched after home test, it considers the back key, menu, and volume up key as not performed.

When I launch this as an independent application, it works fine(app relaunches with previous progress intact) but when I launch it from a deep link URL then this issue arises.

Below is my code of my Service class:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   timer=new Timer();
   TimerTask timerTask=new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           if(getRecentApp().equals(getLauncherPackage())){
               if(VolumeKeyTest.isHomeKeyPressed) {
                   if(!isAppRelaunched) {
                       bringApplicationToFront();
                   }
                   //VolumeKeyTest.isHomeKeyPressed=false;
                   if(timer != null) {
                       timer.cancel();
                       timer.purge();
                       timer = null;
                   }    
                }
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask,0,500);
    //return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void bringApplicationToFront() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VolumeKeyTest.mClass);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    timer = new Timer();
    try{
        pendingIntent.send();
        isAppRelaunched = true;
    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the link 
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

I added this to my `<activity>` tag in manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line to activity in manifest file

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Add this method to the same activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        //do the task here to be refreshed
    }
```

Whenever new intent is called it will open the same actvity which is previously opened. If not then it will open new activity.
Read this more clarification https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: Thanks for the link. It provides a lot of insights of launchModes. Your provided solution did not solve the problem but I solved it using the above mentioned link.